# What can cause RevenueCat to fail during App Review?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, tvos

We are using RevenueCat in a tvOS app. Running locally via the debugger or as a TestFlight build, everything works perfectly, but twice now upon submission to Apple Review, they are unable to retrieve the IAP products and as as result, our purchase buttons read "Not Available" which is the default text set in IB before the prices are retrieved from the network.

We have two RevenueCat entitlements (standard and premium), and two offerings (standard and premium), each with four products (1,3,6 and 12mo). As per the docs, our code looks like:

```
[[RCPurchases sharedPurchases] offeringsWithCompletionBlock:^(RCOfferings* offerings, NSError* error)
{
    RCOffering* standard = [offerings offeringWithIdentifier:kRevenueCatStandardOffering];
    if (standard)
        [self prepareStandardOffering:standard];
        
    RCOffering* premium = [offerings offeringWithIdentifier:kRevenueCatPremiumOffering];
    if (premium)
        [self preparePremiumOffering:premium];
}];
```

and

```
-(void)prepareStandardOffering:(RCOffering *)offering
{
    if (offering && offering.availablePackages.count > 0)
    {
        // Display packages for sale
        NSArray<RCPackage *>* packages = [offering availablePackages];
        for (RCPackage* package in packages)
        {
            UIButton* currentButton = nil;
            
            switch ([package packageType])
            {
                case RCPackageTypeMonthly:    currentButton = [self standardMonthButton];     break;
                case RCPackageTypeThreeMonth: currentButton = [self standardQuarterButton];   break;
                case RCPackageTypeSixMonth:   currentButton = [self standardSixMonthsButton]; break;
                case RCPackageTypeAnnual:     currentButton = [self standardYearButton];      break;

                default: break;
            }

            [currentButton setTitle:[package localizedPriceString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [currentButton setTag:[package packageType]];
            [currentButton setEnabled:YES];
        }       
    }
}
```

App review sent me a screenshot of our app in a state without prices shown. I know they have a good network connection because other data that has to be downloaded appears elsewhere on the screen.

Since it works here and in TestFlight (both in the sandbox environment), why wouldn't it work when Apple runs it during App Review?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly, but if things were working in Testflight builds then it's most likely a product configuration issue in App Store Connect or something wrong with Apple.

There's nothing within RevenueCat that you need to flip over to when you submit an app for review or in production. The way fetching products works with RevenueCat is:

1. Product identifiers are fetched from the RevenueCat server.
2. The SDK attempts to fetch the `SKProducts` from Apple with those identifiers.

For #2, it will either fetch the product or not - there's no error message indicating a failure. So the only error message you could receive would be from #1 if there was a problem fetching the identifiers from RevenueCat.

You didn't mention any errors, and fetching identifiers from RevenueCat is a pretty fail-proof operation, so most likely the issue with fetching the `SKProduct` from Apple.

Unfortunately, since there's no errors, there's no way to know exactly what went wrong - which makes these issues tricky to debug. Since things were working in Testflight, that rules out some things like invalid product identifiers or not having the Paid Applications Agreement signed.

**Are your products in the 'Approved' state?** That is one thing that would cause things to work while testing, but not in review.

I don't want to put any blame on the review team, but there are some horror stories about failing review due to Apple issues. There was a [1-month period this year](https://status.revenuecat.com/incidents/6y3tfs3fyxb7) where a large percentage of apps were getting rejected because sandbox was down. I know that's not a solution, but maybe you can put some logging in to confirm that it's an issue fetching products and if the products array is empty or the requests is just hanging forever with Apple.

Comment: My initial app (with 8 attached IAPs) was rejected for a license issue which we fixed. The IAPs first fell into a status of "Developer Action Needed". I made one edit and they all fell back into "Waiting For Review". When I resubmitted the fixed build with the correct license, there was no way to re-attach the IAPs because they were not in the "Ready To Submit" status and there was no way to get them back into that status.

Everything is now in "Waiting for Review" status.